# How to split an ArrayList in an exact position

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to split an ArrayList "list" into 2 parts. I have to put the first 20% in "T" and the rest 80% in "A". I have another condition. I can only split the database if list.get(i+1).charAt (0) == 'x'.

First, I should put the first 20% of `list` in `T`. Then, I should add from `list` in `T` until `list.get(i+1).charAt (0) == 'x'`.

The second sublist will contain the rest of `list` starting from `list.get(i).charAt (0) == 'x'` which was the stop condition of the sublist `T`. The size of 'T' should be slightly greater than 20%.

the size of the 2 sublists should be equal to the size of `list`.

Example: Input

```
x 0
a 0 <-- 20%
b 0
c 1 <-- T ends here
x 0 <-- A begin here
d 0
...
```

Output (2 files A and T)

file T

```
x 0
a 0 
b 0
c 1
```

file A

```
x 0 
d 0
...
```

My code

```java
int size = list.size()-1;
    int test = (int) (size*0.2);
    String t = "false";
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if ("false".equals(t)){
       if (i < test+10) {
         if ( i > test &&  i < list.size()-1 && (list.get(i+1)).charAt(0) == 'x'){
             t = "true";
          }
          writeT.write(list.get(i)+ "\n");
          }}
       if (i > test && "true".equals(t)) {
          writeA.write(list.get(i)+ "\n");}
}
```

Comment: ```I can only split the database if list.get(i+1).charAt (0) == 'x'```. what is ```i``` here?

Comment: So, are you supposed to split 20/80 by size, or are you supposed to split before `x`? Which is it?

Comment: @Andreas Both by size 20/80 and before line starting with  the char 'x'

Comment: So there might be many sublists? Not just 2? How does that fit with 2 files (T and A)? --- Or did you mean that you want to only split once, at 20% or before `x`, whichever comes first? Or whichever comes last? Or before first `x`, but at 20% if no `x`? Or what?

Comment: I think it's more like a "minimum 20%/maximum 80%" split: T must get first 20% of list, then of the remaining 80%, lines up to but not including `x` also go to T, `x` and all following go to A.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry for the delay! Yes I mean get the first (almost) 20% of the data but I shouldn't stop exactly at 20%, I should stop when I find the first occurrence of `x` after that. and `x` should be in the next sublist `A`. So, the first sublist contains a little more than 20% of `list` (until the first occurrence of `x`).

Comment: Might be good if you edited the question and explained that, you know, to clarity it, because the question is very confusing.

Comment: The second sublist will contain a little less than 80% of `list` starting with `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
List<String> list = ...
int pct = 20;
String prefix = "x";

int idx = list.size() - list.size() * (100 - pct) / 100; // At least pct% of list
while (idx < list.size() && ! list.get(idx).startsWith(prefix))
    idx++;
List<String> part1 = list.subList(0, idx);
List<String> part2 = list.subList(idx, list.size());
```

*Test 1*

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("x 0", "a 0", "b 0", "c 1", "x 0", "d 0", "e 0", "f 0", "g 0",
                                  "h 0", "i 0", "j 0", "k 0", "l 0", "m 0", "n 0", "o 0", "p 0");
// code from above here
System.out.printf("list : %2d %s%n", list.size(), list);
System.out.printf("part1: %2d (%4.1f%%) %s%n", part1.size(), part1.size() * 100d / list.size(), part1);
System.out.printf("part2: %2d (%4.1f%%) %s%n", part2.size(), part2.size() * 100d / list.size(), part2);
```

*Output*

```
list : 18 [x 0, a 0, b 0, c 1, x 0, d 0, e 0, f 0, g 0, h 0, i 0, j 0, k 0, l 0, m 0, n 0, o 0, p 0]
part1:  4 (22.2%) [x 0, a 0, b 0, c 1]
part2: 14 (77.8%) [x 0, d 0, e 0, f 0, g 0, h 0, i 0, j 0, k 0, l 0, m 0, n 0, o 0, p 0]
```

`part1` is slightly greater than 20% and `part2` starts with `x`.
Size of the 2 sublists is equal to the size of `list`.

*Test 2*

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("x 0", "a 0", "b 0", "c 1", "x 0", "d 0");
```

*Output*

```
list :  6 [x 0, a 0, b 0, c 1, x 0, d 0]
part1:  4 (66.7%) [x 0, a 0, b 0, c 1]
part2:  2 (33.3%) [x 0, d 0]
```

`part1` is (a lot) greater than 20% so `part2` can start with `x`.
Size of the 2 sublists is equal to the size of `list`.

Comment: I'm sorry, the size of the 2 sublists should be equal to the size of `list` and the size of `part1` should be slightly greater than 20%.

Comment: @AsmaMekki The size of the 2 sublists *are* equal to the size of list, i.e. `part1.size() + part2.size() == list.size()`. --- Size of `part1` *is* greater than 20% of size of `list`. Whether it is "slightly greater" depends entirely on where the `x` is. --- This is exactly what you were asking for, so I don't understand you comment.